# Netlogo headless on HPC machine error

Tags: google-compute-engine, netlogo

My runninfg netlogo headless on google compute, can someone please help me with this error:

```
abhigenie92_gmail_com@crowds:~$ /home/abhigenie92_gmail_com/netlogo-5.1.0/netlogo-headless.sh \
> --model /home/abhigenie92_gmail_com/copy.nlogo \
> --experiment k-e\
> --table /home/abhigenie92_gmail_com/MyNewOutputData.csv \
> --threads 2
unknown argument: /home/abhigenie92_gmail_com/MyNewOutputData.csv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a space after `k-e` but before the `\`.

Comment: Thanks! That was a silly mistake. Is there any way to check the progress of simulations in headless mode as opposed to gui?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28457997/progress-of-simulations-in-headless-mode