# Progress of simulations in headless mode

Tags: netlogo

Is there any way to check the progress of simulations in headless mode as opposed to gui?
Basic Code:

```
$ ~/netlogo-5.1.0/netlogo-headless.sh \
--model ~/myproject/MyModel.nlogo \
--experiment MyExperiment \
--table ~/myproject/MyNewOutputData.csv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest doing `tail -f ~/myproject/MyNewOutputData.csv`. This will show you a live view of the output file as it is being written to.